# How to check if a column with a given name exists in an excel file

Tags: vb.net

I have an excel file with several columns with data and in order for me to work with the excel file I need to know first if certain columns exist. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio I have been doing some research and found this.

```
 If DataRow.Table.Columns.Contains("column") Then
    MsgBox("YAY")
End If
```

And this

```
 colEmp = Rows(1).Find("Emp#", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
 colEmpName = Rows(1).Find("EmpName", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
 colDepartment = Rows(1).Find("Department", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
 colOrganization = Rows(1).Find("Organization", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
```

Not sure how to apply it in a button. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a button to a form, and an event handler:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    colEmp = Rows(1).Find("Emp#", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    colEmpName = Rows(1).Find("EmpName", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    colDepartment = Rows(1).Find("Department", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    colOrganization = Rows(1).Find("Organization", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column

    'Add whatever else you want to do here...

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, there are many errors. I am new to Visual Basic so I guess I need to initialize variables, not sure how.